# How are Firefox bookmark tags linked to a bookmark?

Tags: json, firefox, bookmarks

I want to manipulate my Firefox bookmarks a bit. I've exported them to a .json file, and read them into my program. Now I'm trying to make sense of the file. I've created a bookmark that looks like this:

[image]

The random strings help me find them in the big lump of JSON. The bookmark object looks like this:

```
{
   "title":"49jy5M9NxD4xOQ13d5me",
   "id":4080,
   "parent":3,
   "dateAdded":1384416939464000,
   "lastModified":1384416982381000,
   "annos":[
      {
         "name":"bookmarkProperties/description",
         "flags":0,
         "expires":4,
         "value":"description"
      }
   ],
   "type":"text/x-moz-place",
   "uri":"http://location/",
   "keyword":"keyword1,keyword2,keyword3"
},
```

But the tags aren't present in there...

If I run a search for the tag string, I find it in a completely different section of the file,

```
{
   "index":2,
   "title":"Tags",
   "id":4,
   "parent":1,
   "dateAdded":1359252968891000,
   "lastModified":1384417276968000,
   "type":"text/x-moz-place-container",
   "root":"tagsFolder",
   "children":[
      {
         "title":"mEszv3zTk1GHQYfTbsZZ",
         "id":4081,
         "parent":4,
         "dateAdded":1384417272962000,
         "lastModified":1384417272962000,
         "type":"text/x-moz-place-container",
         "children":[
            {
               "title":null,
               "id":4082,
               "parent":4081,
               "dateAdded":1384417272962000,
               "lastModified":1384417272962000,
               "type":"text/x-moz-place",
               "uri":"http://location/"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "index":1,
         "title":"QWhcN2Bpl2BBUAtzdkif",
         "id":4083,
         "parent":4,
         "dateAdded":1384417276968000,
         "lastModified":1384417276969000,
         "type":"text/x-moz-place-container",
         "children":[
            {
               "title":null,
               "id":4084,
               "parent":4083,
               "dateAdded":1384417276969000,
               "lastModified":1384417276969000,
               "type":"text/x-moz-place",
               "uri":"http://location/"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
},
```

But there's no discernible link back to the bookmark. None of the IDs line up. So what's the relationship?

Is there a spec on the Firefox bookmark format? I can't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the same process and finally realized that the uri is what links the tag to the bookmark. That's why even when you have a site bookmarked several times and only tag it once, the tags will show up however you visit the site.